# can't output answer at pow function in for loop

Tags: c++

The exercise is" input number a, b and a number list c.
"a" represent the base of the list c, and "b" represent turn the list c to the "b" based number list.
exemple:   a = 2, b = 3, c = 10110
The answer would be "211"

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main() {

int a,b; 
int account, d, size, sum = 0;
char *c, *w;
cout<<"Input two stander a b first, them input a based listed"<<endl; 
cin>>a>>b;
cin.ignore();
cin.getline (c,64);
size = strlen(c);   
d = atoi(c);
for(int i = 0;  i<size; i++){
    account = (d%a)*pow(a,i);
    sum+=account;
    d = (d/a);
}
w = itoa(sum, w, b);
cout<<"the list after transfer:  "<<w<<endl; 


return 0;
}
```

My program can come through the compiler, but my computer just can't conculate the data. I anxiously don't know where my program is wrong. I thought it might be the pow function in the for loop. 
Could any one help me?

Comment: It'd help if you allocate some memory for `c`. Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: you should allocate memory for w, too.

Comment: `c` is uninitialised.   The input statement `cin.getline(c, 64)` gives undefined behaviour, since `getline()` ASSUMES it is passed a valid address (to the first character in a buffer).

Comment: Don't use `char *`. Use `std::string`.

Comment: Yeah, debugger...............

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and made two changes: 
instead of char *c, *w; -> char c[256], w[256]; (My compilator was throwing exception, did not like *c here)

and instead of w = itoa(sum, w, b); ->  _itoa_s(sum, w, b);

I tested it using 2 3 101 and got the 'list after transfer 12'. Hope this work.

However, there was still a warning "conversion from double to int", which should be treated as an error.